# Running a c++ exe inside a C# application Problem

Tags: c#, c++

I have a c++ exe that I am trying to run in a C# project. Every time I try it the console opens up with the output and is not outputted to the panel as desired. This works if I use another exe created in C#.

Is this even possible using a C++ exe or am I missing something?

cheers

my code: 
http://pastebin.com/n1vXsknB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console applications have the option of creating and writing to the console instead of their output streams. In this case, there's nothing you can do, short of hooking using Detours.

If you can change the C++ program, then you can make it use its output streams instead of the console.

Comment: hmmmm, as I have zero experience of C++ I don't think that will be possible :(

Comment: I did try this with a regular console app that wrote to the console and it worked fine. How come you have to change it to write to the output stream with the C++ exe and not with a C# exe?

Comment: It's not a C++/C# difference. The C++ program may be writing directly to the console, or it may be using a standard library that writes to the console instead of the output stream. The reason you don't see this in C# is because the BCL does not expose the console directly. You can still p/Invoke in C# to directly write to the console, and that would give you the same behavior.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. Should I just forget about including the output in the panel and have it in the console?
cheers

Comment: Yes, unless you can modify the C++ program.